# What's making my web crawler slow?

Tags: php, curl, apache2

> Hi! I'm making a web crawler using php. At first when I'm just getting
>   the web content (using the function get_links), it was fast but then
>   after all the other function have been added it became painfully slow.
>   My web crawler is literally crawling. When I check the Network monitor
>   in Inspector I got no response for the request at all. What could be
>   the problem? is internet speed a factor? why is it taking too long to
>   load? if you may ask, My flatform is Ubuntu 15.4 and I'm just using a
>   localhost as a server. Here is my code.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');


    $to_crawl = "http://bestspace.com";
    $c = array();
    $i = 0;

    function get_links($url) {
        global $c;
        $input  = @file_get_contents($url);
        $regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\">]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";
        preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $input, $matches);
        $base_url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
        $l = $matches[2];

        foreach($l as $link) {

            if (strpos($link, "#")) {
                $link = substr($link, 0, strpos($link, "#"));
            }
            if (substr($link,0,1) == ".") {
                $link = substr($link, 1);
            }
            if (substr($link,0,7) == "http://") {
                $link = $link;
            }
            else if (substr($link,0,8) == "https://") {
                $link = $link;
            }
            else if (substr($link,0,2) == "//") {
                $link = substr($link, 2);
            }
            else if (substr($link,0,1) == "#") {
                $link = $url;
            }
            else if (substr($link,0,7) == "mailto:") {
                $link = "[".$link."]";
            }
            else {
                if (substr($link, 0, 1) != "/") {
                    $link = $base_url."/".$link;
                }
                else {
                    $link = $base_url.$link;
                }
            }

            if (substr($link, 0, 7) != "http://" && substr($link, 0, 8) != "https://" && substr($link, 0, 1) != "[") {
                if (substr($link, 0, 8) == "https://") {
                    $link = "https://".$link;
                }
                else {
                    $link = "http://".$link;
                }
            }
            //echo $link."<br/>";
            if (!in_array($link, $c)) {
                array_push($c, $link);
            }

        }
    }

    get_links($to_crawl);
    //echo "ARRAY <br />";
    foreach ($c as $page) {
        # code...
        get_links($page);
        //echo $page."<br />";
    }


    function get_domain($url)
    {
        $host = @parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
        if (!$host)
            $host = $url;

        if (substr($host, 0, 4) == "www.")
            $host = substr($host, 4);

        if (strlen($host) > 50)
            $host = substr($host, 0, 47) . '...';

        return $host;
    }


    function content_type($url) {

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1) ;
        $content = curl_exec($ch);
        if(!curl_errno($ch))
            {
                $info = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);

            }
    return $info;
    curl_close($ch);

    }


        echo "<table class = 'table table-striped'>";
        echo "<tbody>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>#</th><th>DOMAIN NAME</th><th>CATEGORY</th><th>URL</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
    foreach ($c as $page) {
        $i++;
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td >".$i."</td><td>".get_domain($to_crawl)."</td><td>".content_type($page)."</td><td>".$page;
        echo "</td>";

        echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";

    ?>
```

Comment: Hi @RealJho did you tried simplehtmldom? it will help you to not reinvent the wheel and use your custom functions but simple jquery like functions for taking info from links, tables etc.. :)

Comment: @oserk Does this mean that parsing makes it slow?

Comment: it could be your regex that is making too much matches or to much looping is in you get_doman or get_links functions that are making your script to work slowly, I don't know didn't replicated your code so I couldn't debug it,, but you should reconsider the simplehtmldom lib I sent you link to..

Comment: Hi @oserk I tried using simplehtmldom, it's incredibly fast. but it's only fetching html scripts. What I want is to get .js scripts and images. can you suggest how should I do that? or how could I make a good regex for preg_match?

Comment: I think that is another question and not related with fast html fetching / parsing. if my suggestion to your problem helped or solved your initial problem please mark it as solved and ask another question, but please post some specific problem with js files that you ran to .. hth, kreso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to send you link to investigate it thoroughly because it is just like jquery for the web. It is high quality peace of software for web crawling and you will be much more productive, trust me!

Take a look at examples and thank me later :)

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

hth, k